# How to speed up "three finger drag" delay on release?

Tags: macos, trackpad

It takes about 300ms after a three finger drag for it to take effect. I notice the delay because an actual *click* drag releases instantly

Anyone know of a hack to get rid of it??

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to wait for the drag to be released before moving the cursor again. If you move the cursor with just one finger after the three finger drag, the drag will be released instantly.

Comment: Moving the cursor releases the drag, but typing doesn't, so if, for example, you drag and then hit enter, your input will be ignored. This is incredibly frustrating for me when using Lightroom and trying to view and sort photos.

Answer (score 3):

I have also been frustrated by this problem and found a github app that fixes the annoying delay.

Now I can copy and paste without the delay!

https://github.com/pravdomil/no-drag-release-delay

disclaimer: I have not association with the github, just thought I would share the solution I found

Comment: This little app still works for me on macOS Catalina. (It's been years this little annoyance have been bothering me, so thank you for the pointer!)